# How to convert a dynamic table to a jquery data table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I am dynamically creating a HTML table from [json data](https://api.myjson.com/bins/1oaye). I then want to convert this table to a datatable. But when I try to do this I keep getting an error that reads:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined`

My jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#action-button').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1oaye',
                    data: {
                        format: 'json'
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
                        var col = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            for (var key in data[i]) {
                                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                                    col.push(key);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
                        var table = document.createElement("table");


                        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

                        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

                        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
                            th.innerHTML = col[i];
                            tr.appendChild(th);
                        }

                        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

                            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                                tabCell.innerHTML = data[i][col[j]];
                            }
                        }

                        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
                        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
                        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
                        divContainer.appendChild(table);

                        // convert it to a data table
                        table.setAttribute("id", "example");
                        $('#example').DataTable();

                    },
                    type: 'GET'
                });
            });
        });
```

How do I create or convert a dynamic table to a data table from json?

[JSFiddle showing the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/obz5dLtv/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just having a quick look at the DataTable code and it looks like the likely reason is that you haven't put the `<th>` in a `<thead>` section. Currently they sit within `<tbody>`.

Here's the updated fiddle...
https://jsfiddle.net/8some9a0/1/

Comment: I figured that might be the issue. Do you know how I could wrap the <th> in a <thead>?

Comment: var header = table.createTHead();
 var row = header.insertRow(0);

Comment: Thanks K Scandrett, Gets 1 step closer. It removes the error but the data table functionality still doesn't work. If you look under the table it says `No data available in table` and if you try and search or sort it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: That's because the fiddle just puts everything under <thead> now.... Sorry, let me see if I can fix that.